# Run .tex files in batch in xeLaTex

Tags: xetex

I have 50 similar `.tex` files that need to be run in XeLaTeX, and would like to run them in batch mode. Does anyone know if this can be done in Windows?  File names are:

```
file1.tex
file2.tex
file3.tex
...
```

Comment: Since the format for compilation is simply `xelatex file1.tex`, this a question more apt for SU.

Comment: Why is it off-topic? The workflow how to best get from source to result should be on-topic.

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen I guess because it's about doing batch processes on Windows: the fact that it's a TeX process to be batched doesn't actually alter the approach needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using TeX Live, then a `latexmk` with `pdflatex` set to `xelatex` should do the trick.

I.e. (untested)

```
latexmk -e '$pdflatex=\'xelatex\'' *.tex
```

though I don't know if `*` works on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use the following batch-file:

```
For /F %%F IN ('DIR /B *.tex') DO (
CALL xelatex %%F
)
```